# detect duplicate but ignore a value on PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I know how to detect duplicate value in PHP array by using `array_diff_key( $x , array_unique( $x ) );`.

My problem is I want to detect duplicate value in PHP array, but ignore a value or NULL value. For example:

```
$x = array (1,0,0,0,4,4,3);
$x = array (1,NULL,NULL,NULL,4,4,3);
```

I want to detect 4 without changing the array structure (array length must still 7).
Is this possible in PHP ? How to do that?

Comment: `Is this possible in PHP ?` yes, it is possible with php

Comment: 1. read rules of this site 2. write code 3. post clear question

Comment: You can use `array_intersect_assoc`

Comment: Use `array_filter` to remove the values you want to ignore before checking for duplicates. None of these functions change the original array structure, they return new arrays.

Comment: Please explain it in detail

Comment: @Barmar yes, you were right. Using array_filter then array_diff_key. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$y = array_filter($x,function($d){return $x!==null;});
$z = array_diff_key($y,array_unique($y));
```

`$y` has only the items NOT null.

`$z` has the keys of the duplicate items from `$x` that are not null.

Answer (score 0):

I could do the following custom function `detectArr`:

```
<?php
$x = array (1,0,0,0,4,4,3);

    function detectArr($arr){
       $output = array();
       foreach ($arr as $i){
            if ($i){
                    $output[] = $i;
            }
            else{
                    $output[] = NULL;
            }        
       }
        return $output;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(detectArr($x));
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://codepad.org/W8ocL6dj